# Accessing classes with MYSQL lookups in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, class

I'm part-way through making a simple comments system with PHP. With every comment that I have, I want to look up the user that made that comment and get their details too.

My classes are as follows:

```
class getuser {
    public function __construct($userid) {
        $userquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ".$userid."";
        $userresult = mysql_query($userquery);
        while($user = mysql_fetch_array($userresult)){
            $this->uid = $user['id'];
            $this->username = $user['username'];
            $this->avatar = $user['avatar'];
        }
    }
}
class getcomment {
    public function __construct($postid) {
        $commentquery = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postid = ".$postid."";
        $commentresult = mysql_query($commentquery);
        while($comment = mysql_fetch_array($commentresult)){
            $this->uid = $comment['uid'];
            $this->comment = $comment['comment'];
            $this->timestamp = $comment['timestamp'];
            $this->likes = $comment['likes'];
            $this->reported = $comment['reported'];

            //get user info for this comment
            $this->getuser = new getuser($this->uid);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having problems with accessing this information on my page...

```
                $comments = new getcomment($postid);

                foreach($comments as $comment){

                  echo $comment->username."<br>";

}
```

There are two comments in the db with this post id. Is it the while loops that are causing the issue? How do I return all of the comments with the relevant user info attached to each?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop is fine, what is not fine is your constructor for getcomment,
because you are override each of the `$this` property during the loop.

Also, `$comments` is an object, not an array.
Possible fix :-

Constrcutor:-

```
 $this->comments = array();
 $idx = 0;
 while($comment = mysql_fetch_object($commentresult))
 {
   $this->comments[$idx] = $comment;
   $this->comments[$idx]->getuser = new getuser($comment->uid);
   ++$idx;
}
```

Accessing :-

```
$obj = new getcomment($postid);
foreach($obj->comments as $comment)
{
  echo $comment->getuser->username."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I improve what I've written above? and how do I loop through the 'object(s)'?

Comment: I just update an example, actually you have more problems than just what I have mention. You should spent some efforts to read some example of OO design, this will help you understanding better.

Comment: How can I do this without using $comment[1]->getuser->username ? Without the array number it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: what do you mean? Can you `var_dump($comment);` to check on the object (single object)?

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (9) { ["id"]=> string(3) "113" ["qid"]=> string(2) "13" ["aid"]=> string(1) "0" ["uid"]=> string(1) "1" ["comment"]=> string(31) "3333333333333333333333333333333" ["likes"]=> string(1) "0" ["reported"]=> string(1) "0" ["timestamp"]=> string(19) "2011-12-06 10:52:51" ["getuser"]=> object(getuser)#4 (4) { ["uid"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(3) "Tim" ["avatar"]=> string(0) "" ["monster"]=> string(43) "/admin/monsterid/monsters/1300952901924.png" } }

Comment: [1]=> object(stdClass)#5 (9) { ["id"]=> string(3) "101" ["qid"]=> string(2) "13" ["aid"]=> string(1) "0" ["uid"]=> string(1) "1" ["comment"]=> string(20) "12`1`1`12`12`12`2`12" ["likes"]=> string(1) "0" ["reported"]=> string(1) "0" ["timestamp"]=> string(19) "2011-12-06 07:57:56" ["getuser"]=> object(getuser)#6 (4) { ["uid"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(3) "Tim" ["avatar"]=> string(0) "" ["monster"]=> string(43) "/admin/monsterid/monsters/1300952901924.png" } } }

Comment: i think you are var_dump($comments), instead of var_dump($comment);

Comment: i think you have overlook something at the mysql_fetch_object, can you double check? It should set the $comment into $this->comments, and when you iterate $comments->comments --> refer to single objet (Not an array of objects)

Comment: on boi, I have make a changes twice, can you double check? is a straight forward while-loop

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better if You would create a "getUser" function instead of a getuser property. Or at least don't name classes and properties "getUser".

And You really should not have multiple records sharing the same index. Use a UNIQUE index. Also assign a Foreign Key on the userid field of the comments table.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've done it, you should be echo'ing $comment->getuser->username.

The class structure you're using here is a little odd.  I would suggest the following:

```
<?php

class Comment {

  public $uid, $comment, $timestamp, $likes, $reported;
  protected $user;

  public function __construct($result_data)
  {
    foreach ($result_data as $k => $v)
    {
      $this->$k = $v;
    }
  }

  public function getUser()
  {
    if (empty($this->user))
    {
      $userquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ".$this->uid."";
      $userresult = mysql_query($userquery);
      $this->user = mysql_fetch_object($userresult);
    }

    return $this->user;
  }

  public static function get_by_post_id($postid)
  {
    $commentquery = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postid = ".$postid."";
    $commentresult = mysql_query($commentquery);
    $results = array();
    while($comment_data = mysql_fetch_array($commentresult))
    {
      $results[] = new Comment($comment_data);
    }
    return $results;
  }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
<?php
$comments = Comment::get_by_post_id($postid);
foreach ($comments as $comment)
{
  echo $comment->getUser()->username;
}
```